# What is the expected time of the 'sudo snap refresh' command to take?

Tags: snap

I kept getting notifications that snap was outdated and needed to be updated.

I came across instructions to run from a terminal:

```
sudo snap refresh
```

Since invoking the command about 45 minutes ago, I am just starting at a spinning curser.

Note: I quit snap and snapd -- via kill commands prior to invocation.

Comment: killing snapd was probably the problem here, how is `snap` supposed to do anything if you killed `snapd`?

Answer (score 1):

Snap commands should provide immediate feedback and lots of ongoing download/install status updates on the screen.

However, since you killed snapd before starting this adventure, it's probably time for you to save your work and reboot your machine.

Rebooting should also, coincidentally, refresh the snap that you received the notification about.

**In the future**, you don't need to kill snapd. You generally don't need to kill the snapped application -- simply Quitting from the application is enough for a properly-behaving application. Then `sudo snap refresh`. Then restart your application.